# Insert multiple textbox values into sql database

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 textboxes to add Skills, that goes into one column called 'SkillName'. 
However, I'm getting this error.

```
'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But I have used the assembly using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

This is my code to add textboxes-

```
 public void InsertSkillInfo()
        {


            String str = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);

            try
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    **string skill = (Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Text;**
                    const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Cert (SkillName) VALUES (@SkillName)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["@SkillName"].Value = skill;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Page.FindControl` will return a `Control`, but you want a textbox. If you are sure that the control it finds will always be a textbox, then cast it to a textbox.

Either:

```
string skill = (TextBox)((Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString()))).Text;
```

or

```
var skill = "";
var control = Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString()) as TextBox;
if(control != null {
    skill = control.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But now its showing error near Parameter-
An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@SkillName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Try adding your parameter with something like this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillName", skill);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the control to a TexBox so it should be this

```
string skill = ((TextBox) Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it simply like this

```
string skill = ((TextBox)(Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString()))).Text;
```

Comment: Thanks.. But now its showing error near Parameter- An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@SkillName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Comment: That is VERY much open to SQL injection attacks. What would happen if someone entered a skill called `') go drop table Cert go --`?